# Добавить список в dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql

Мне надо создать столбец подстановки в моем приложении, таблицы связаны внешним ключом.
Говорят, в Microsoft SQL Server нет такой функции, как тогда мне это реализовать?

Comment: Не поясните что такое "столбец подстановки"?

Comment: Это когда я могу заполнить поле только определенными значениями из списка, который появляется при выделении ячейки. Аналог в access выглядит так: http://gyazo.com/3df7c31dab836758b867f33ed4fd0f49

Comment: База данных никак не связана с тем, как вы её отображаете. Можно отображать любой столбец любым возможным способом.

Ваш вопрос не к базе данных, а к используемому UI-фреймворку.

Answer (score 1):

Вам следовало бы, конечно, указать UI-фреймворк, который используете.

На примере wpf, могу предложить такой вариант: в codebehind формы можно прописать источник строк для столбца.

```
public TaskWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
grid.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Tasks;//все записи
//записи выбора колонки моделей (источником может быть любой список)
modelColumn.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Models.Select(a=>a.Name).OrderBy(s => s).ToList();//в список выбора попадают только значения. Получается просто список выбора без связывания с другой таблицей
}
```

Разметка таблицы в этом случае (выбранное значение (строка) попадает в свойство ModelName редактируемой строки таблицы):

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Модель" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ModelName}"  x:Name="ModelColumn" />
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Количество" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

</DataGrid>

В случае связывания таблиц, необходимо подставить список объектов, содержащих Id и отображаемое свойство (в данном случае Name), или полностью всю сущность.

```
public TaskWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
grid.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Tasks;//все записи
//записи выбора колонки моделей (источником может быть любой список)
modelColumn.ItemsSource = _dataContext.Models.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();//в список выбора попадают сущности с Id
}
```

Тогда чуть изменится и разметка. Необходимо указать, какое свойство выбираемой сущности отображать в списке (DisplayMemberPath="Name")  и связывание нужно делать целиком с сущьностью или её идентификатором (SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Model} или SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ModelId}).

```
<DataGrid Name="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Модель" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Model}"  x:Name="ModelColumn" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Количество" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Насколько я помню, в WinForms похожая ситуация (могу ошибаться).

Answer (score 0):

Cудя по `dataGridView` предполагаю, что вопрос все-таки относится к `WinForm`.

Для примера, все приведу в коде. Но то же самое можно сделать через конструктор (думаю там все найдете сами).

```
// Создаем столбец
dgvComboBox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
// Указываем имя столбца нашей таблицы, которое будет выводится в наш dgvComboBox
dgvComboBox.DataPropertyName = "DictField";
// Добавляем его к нашему dataGridView
dataGridView.Columns.Add(dgvComboBox);
```

Получаем справочные данные. Пусть наша таблица имеет два поля: `ID` и `Name`

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Dict;";
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // Загружаем в DataTable. Можно использовать и другие контейнеры, например List<T>
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);
    // Указываем источник данных
    dgvComboBox.DataSource = dt;
    // Указывваем что будет являтся значением при получении/установки
    dgvComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
    // Указываем что показывать пользователю
    dgvComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

Дальше получаем сами данные, с которыми хотим работать